# Invalid argument error when running docker images in ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to run some docker images in Ubuntu but keep encountering this error. This is the command I'm executing:

[image]

This is the error that's being returned:

[image]

The image has been loaded correctly as indicated here:

[image]

The volume that I'm trying to run also exists so I'm not sure what the issue is. I've also tried running the command without the volume argument and just the file name like so: `sudo docker run -d --publish 5001:80 backend-api-local`, but the same error is returned.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: When you say "this is the command I'm executing", you follow that with a non-runnable PNG file.  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] and any relevant error messages as text, not images?

Answer (score 0):

From the listing above we can see that some rule in iptables doesnt allow traffic on port 5001 (blocks it). Maybe it is pruden to have a look at its rules, for example iptables -L or switch it off for a while (service iptables stop) or restart it.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the error means in a little more detail? I did some research but am still quite confused. I also tried changing the port and looked at the rules but still no solution yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded WSL and that solved my issue